# How to search for all points in a given radius of a zipcode with google maps api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way with Google Maps API, that I can find all red balloon points (addresses pinned on my google map) within a given radius (in miles) of a certain zip code?

For example...

- The first input box asks you for your zip code.  Type it in.
- The second input box (a section box with < options >) asks you for
  the radius in miles, 10 miles, 20 miles, 30 miles..etc
- Then you click submit
- Then the google map shows all the addresses (which were stored from a
  json file), on to the google map in red balloons.

Is there free learning material on the web that will help me to build something like this?

I've been reading google maps api stuff all morning and haven't found any examples that can offer this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the two high-level steps you need to follow to implement this:

1) You want to convert that zipcode (or an address in many different forms!) to a latitude and longitude coordinate using the Google Geocoder API.

2) Dynamically create a GET request to a script that queries your database based on the distance the user entered (5 miles, 10 miles, etc.) like so:

```
var searchUrl = 'phpsqlajax_search.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
```

Look at my answer to this related question so you can take user input and geocode the address: [Store locatore, how to use/input my postion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11663765/store-locatore-how-to-use-input-my-postion/11674732#11674732)

The Google Maps API provides extensive documentation on finding the closest items in a database to a certain latitude and longitude coordinate.  It can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

Note: The documentation uses PHP, Javascript, and MySQL.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't have PHP or MySQL at hand for this project.  I'm trying to do this with javascript and json.  That tutorial really gets me annoyed because what if you are not using PHP and MySQL.  What if you are in a Microsoft Environment??? Or what if you are depending on json to store your address information and not a database.  It seems that there should be more options on how to go about this...

Comment: Where are you getting the markers from that are loaded onto the map?

Comment: As far as markers - I am taking a shot in the dark in trying to load my markers with json - http://blog.sofasurfer.org/2011/06/27/dynamic-google-map-markers-via-simple-json-file/

Comment: Cool, so you want to make a script file that you call with a radius parameter. When the script (can be javascript) is called, it looks through the JSON file using very similar logic to the SQL query shown in the Google documentation.

`SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;`

Answer (score 2):

When you just want an approximation and a fast result you can also try a space filling curve, i.e. a spatial index. Look for example the internet map from xkcd comic. It uses a hilbert curve to print a map from the internet. Then you can use the curve to transform the geo locations and relax the nearest-neighbor search. The same curve is used in many database engines with the point datatype and a spatial index.

Here you have a javascript hilbert curve: https://github.com/chrisdew/jshilbert.
Here a blog about spatial index: http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves. I have wrote a php class hilbert-curve @ phpclasses.org. It also uses a mercator projection.

Comment: You mean to tell me there is no way to set the radius of your centered balloon points with the zoom feature in google maps api? or something to that effect???  I can't believe the answer is no.  That seems so unrealistic with all that a developer can do with Google Maps!

Comment: By center I meant the visual perspective of seeing all the addresses on your browser window.  I should of just left the word out.

Comment: chiyou, when you say JavaScript hilbert curve, is that the same as the examples mentioned on this page... http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html